# General sorting for any type, struggling with structures

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I'm having some trouble implementing a general sorting algorithm for any type. I've got the general sorting down, but I can't figure out how to write a compare function for structures I've made. The structures are automobiles, which have a name, model year, and price. I'm comparing the years, and sorting them in ascending order.

So far, I've written functions for sorting strings which works with the general algorithm. The general sorting algorithm is written correctly I believe and it is designed here in `sort.c`:

```
#include "sort.h"
#include <string.h>


/* Swap two pointers.                                                                                                                                                                                          */
static
void swap(void** left, void** right) {
  void* temp = *left;
  *left = *right;
  *right = temp;
}

/* Sort Array                                                                                                                           
 * This function sorts the data stored in the array.
 * The actual sorting routine is                                                                    
 * Bubble-Sort.                                                                                                                         
 */
void sort_array(void* Array[], unsigned size, int (*compare)(void*,void*))
{
  int i;
  int have_swapped = 1;

  while (have_swapped) {
    have_swapped = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i ){
      if (compare(Array[i],Array[i+1])) {
        swap(&Array[i+1], &Array[i]);
        have_swapped = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think I have written the code for `compare_structs` correctly, but when I try to run the program it enters an infinite loop in the terminal. I have no idea why it's doing this.

I'm trying to learn C and passing pointers/functions as arguments. I want to write this `compare_structs` program so that it fits with the general sorting algorithm in `sort.c`, so I believe it has to return `-1` in order to be swapped. I can't find the bug that's causing an infinite loop. Any help is appreciated!

Here is `sort_structs.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sort.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Automobile */
struct automobile {
  const char* name;
  unsigned year;
  unsigned price;
};

struct automobile one = { "AMC Pacer", 1975, 12900 };
struct automobile two = { "Cadillac Fleetwood", 1981, 4995 };
struct automobile three = { "Ford Pinto", 1971, 4200 };
struct automobile four = { "Suzuki X90", 1996, 1625 };
struct automobile five = { "Chrysler TC", 1991, 2495 };
struct automobile six = { "Cadillac Cimarron", 1986, 4990 };
struct automobile seven = { "Plymouth Prowler", 1997, 60000 };
struct automobile eight =  { "Ford Edsel", 1958, 17000 };
struct automobile nine =  { "Yugo", 1985, 3990 };
struct automobile ten =  { "Pontiac Aztek", 2001, 603 };

/* Test Data
 * Here I'm creating an array that points to the structures defined
 */
unsigned data_size = 10;
struct automobile* data[10] = {
  &one,
  &two,
  &three,
  &four,
  &five,
  &six,
  &seven,
  &eight,
  &nine,
  &ten
};

static
int compare_structs(void* left, void* right) {
  struct automobile *x = left;
  struct automobile *y = right;
  int xYear = x->year;
  int yYear = y->year;
  if (xYear > yYear) return -1;
}

/* Test program
 *
 * This program tests sort_array with an array of automobile objects.  Or
 * rather, an array of pointers to automobile objects.
 */
int main() {
  int i;
  int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

  sort_array((void**)data, data_size, &compare_structs);
for(i = 0; i < data_size - 1; ++i) {
    if (data[i]->year > data[i+1]->year)  {
      fprintf(stderr, "\"%s\" and \"%s\" are out of order\n",data[i]->name, data[i+1]->name);
      status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  return status;
}
```

Comment: Please prune your code segment and show us just relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were quite a number of changes that I made in order to get the code to function. I'll do what I can to recall and explain each of them.

**1. Call to sort_array**

You originally called sort_array like this:

`sort_array((void**)data, data_size, &compare_structs);`

While it needs to (a) just cast the data variable to a void* and (b) doesn't need the address-of operator before the compare-function. (if you refer to a function but don't call it, the statement evaluates as the address of the function)

The result is:

`sort_array((void*)data, data_size, compare_structs);`

**2. return value from compare_structs**
You only returned a value from `compare_structs` if the year value of left is greater that the year value of right. You should return 1 of 3 values. -1, 0 and 1 to facilitate ascending/descending sort, with the 0 indicating that no swap is required.

`if (xYear > yYear) return -1;`

becomes

`return (xYear - yYear);`

**3. Checking the return value from compare**
You originally only checked if the return was something. You can check for greater than 0 or less than 0 to allow for ascending/descending sort order.
Thus,

`if (compare(Array[i],Array[i+1]))`

becomes (for an ascending order sort)

`if (compare(Array[i],Array[i+1]) > 0)`

Collating these modifications and running the result with a small mod to print the output, results in the following being printed to the console.

```
0. - 1958
1. - 1971
2. - 1975
3. - 1981
4. - 1985
5. - 1986
6. - 1991
7. - 1996
8. - 1997
9. - 2001
```

Finally, here's the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "sort.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>


/* Swap two pointers.                                                                                                                                                                                          */
static
void swap(void** left, void** right)
{
    void* temp = *left;
    *left = *right;
    *right = temp;
}

/* Sort Array
 * This function sorts the data stored in the array.
 * The actual sorting routine is
 * Bubble-Sort.
 */
void sort_array(void* Array[], unsigned size, int (*compare)(void*,void*))
{
    int i;
    int have_swapped = 1;

    while (have_swapped)
    {
        have_swapped = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i )
        {
            if (compare(Array[i],Array[i+1]) > 0)
            {
                swap(&Array[i+1], &Array[i]);
                have_swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    i = 100;
}





/* Automobile

 */
struct automobile
{
    const char* name;
    unsigned year;
    unsigned price;
};

struct automobile one =
{
    "AMC Pacer",
    1975,
    12900
};

struct automobile two =
{
    "Cadillac Fleetwood",
    1981,
    4995
};

struct automobile three =
{
    "Ford Pinto",
    1971,
    4200
};

struct automobile four =
{
    "Suzuki X90",
    1996,
    1625
};

struct automobile five =
{
    "Chrysler TC",
    1991,
    2495
};

struct automobile six =
{
    "Cadillac Cimarron",
    1986,
    4990
};

struct automobile seven =
{
    "Plymouth Prowler",
    1997,
    60000
};

struct automobile eight =
{
    "Ford Edsel",
    1958,
    17000
};

struct automobile nine =
{
    "Yugo",
    1985,
    3990
};

struct automobile ten =
{
    "Pontiac Aztek",
    2001,
    603
};

/* Test Data
 * Here I'm creating an array that points to the structures defined
 */
unsigned data_size = 10;
struct automobile* data[10] =
{
    &one,
    &two,
    &three,
    &four,
    &five,
    &six,
    &seven,
    &eight,
    &nine,
    &ten
};

static
int compare_structs(void* left, void* right)
{
    struct automobile *x = left;
    struct automobile *y = right;
    int xYear = x->year;
    int yYear = y->year;
    //if (xYear > yYear) return -1;
    return (xYear - yYear);
}
/* Test program
 *
 * This program tests sort_array with an array of automobile objects.  Or
 * rather, an array of pointers to automobile objects.
 */
int main()
{
    int i;
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    sort_array((void*)data, data_size, compare_structs);

    for(i = 0; i < data_size - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (data[i]->year > data[i+1]->year)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\"%s\" and \"%s\" are out of order\n",data[i]->name, data[i+1]->name);
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<data_size; i++)
        printf("%d. - %d\n", i, data[i]->year);

    return status;
}
```